# androidTest not giving any result

Tags: testing, android-espresso, android-testing, instrumented-test

I am running a UI test but it just keeps loading and not giving any success or failed but same code if I am running test on another Android Studio it is giving success. I've reinstalled the Android Studio also but no result.

Android Studio Version - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

[image]